Really struggling with my mod script for an RSA decryption
I've been working on an RSA decryption problem using Matlab and I don't know what I'm missing. The problem gives me n, e, and c and it states no factoring n. The two possible messages are very short; "one" or "two." I believe I've found p, q, n, phi_n, and n. I just can't get my mod script to give me the correct plaintext.
Since the problem says I can't factor n, I used the quadratic equation to get p and q, and then I was able to find d and phi_d. I then factored n to see if I got the same values and I did. I also used smaller values with the quadratic equation script to make sure it was correct and it was. I also did that whole process with known values and it worked.
A friend verified my values with a python script and they get 151405 (one). My Matlab script gives me 690945826910. I know I'm doing something extremely wrong here but I can't figure out what.
function decrypt_script()
    % Given values
    C = 273095689186;  % Ciphertext
    d = 368022327335;  % Private key exponent
    n = 712446816787;  % Modulus

    % Decrypt the ciphertext
    plaintext = mod_exp(C, d, n);

    % Output the result
    fprintf('Plaintext: %d\n', plaintext);
end

function result = mod_exp(base, exp, mod_val)
    % Perform modular exponentiation using the method of exponentiation by squaring.
    %
    % Parameters:
    % base (int): The base number to be exponentiated.
    % exp (int): The exponent.
    % mod_val (int): The modulus for the operation.
    %
    % Returns:
    % int: Result of (base^exp) % mod_val

    result = 1;  % Initialize result to 1 (neutral element for multiplication)

    while exp > 0  % While there are still bits in the exponent
        if mod(exp, 2) == 1  % If the current bit of the exponent is 1
            result = mod(result * base, mod_val);  % Multiply result by base and take modulo
        end
        base = mod(base * base, mod_val);  % Square the base and take modulo
        exp = floor(exp / 2);  % Move to the next bit in the exponent
    end
end


What is the value of e? I suspect you have overthought this by using a "quadratic equation" to recover p and q. That's still probably considered factoring. The solution to the problem, if I understand it correctly, is almost trivial, and is designed to illustrate why padding of the plaintext in RSA encryption is needed for security.

Also, what is the encoding that results in "one" becoming 151405?

I don't know matlab but https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html says it defaults to double-precision floating-point (IEEE 754) which can represent exact integers only up to 15.9 digits, and you are trying to use 24 digit values that need to be exact. @PresidentJamesK.Polk: apparently base-100 with 01-26 for the alphabet; IME this is common for introductory presentations that don't want to deal with the complications of real systems (like "why is 48 zero?")
